# Kalman Filter prediction error estimation: why two constants and transposed matrices?

Tags: prediction, kalman-filter

Hy everybody!

I have found a very informative and good tutorial for understanding Kalman Filter. In the end, I would like to understand the Extended Kalman Filter in the second half of the tutorial, but first I want to solve any mystery.

[Kalman Filter tutorial](http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/kalman_tutorial/) Part 6. 
I think we use constant for prediction error, because the new value in a certain k time moment can be different, than the previous. But why we use two constants? It says:

> we multiply twice by a because the prediction error pk is itself a squared error; hence, it is scaled by the square of the coefficient associated with the state value xk.

I can't see the meaning of this sentence.

And later in the EKF he creates a matrix and a transposed matrix from that (in Part 12). Why the transposed one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The Kalman filter maintains error estimates as *variances*, which are squared standard deviations.  When you multiply a Gaussian random variable `N(x,p)` by a constant `a`, you increase its standard deviation by a factor of `a`, which means its variance increases as `a^2`.  He's writing this as `a*p*a` to maintain a parallel structure when he converts from a scalar state to a matrix state.  If you have an error coviarance matrix `P` representing state `x`, then the error covariance of `Ax` is `APA^T` as he shows in part 12.  It's a convenient shorthand for doing that calculation.  You can expand the matrix multiplication by hand to see that the coefficients all go in the right place.

If any of this is fuzzy to you, I strongly recommend you read a tutorial on Gaussian random variables.  Between `x` and `P` in a Kalman filter, your success depends a lot more on you understanding `P` than `x`, even though most people get started by being interested in improving `x`.